# Spring Cloud Stream: Are commit calls guaranteed to happen after method annotated @StreamListener("errorChannel") if enableAutoCommitOnError=true?

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

Consider I have set SCS property `enableAutoCommitOnError=true` (and `enableAutoCommitOffset=true` and `ackEachRecord=true` as well)

And I have a method that listens for errors as follows:

```
@StreamListener("errorChannel")
public void handleError(ErrorMessage errorMessage, @Headers MessageHeaders messageHeaders)
{
...
}
```

My questions are:

- Is the ***call*** to commit guaranteed to happen after `handleError` exits?
- Will the offset be ***attempted*** to be committed if `handleError` itself throws exception?

From my tests it seems that the answer to both the questions is yes, but I am not sure if it is guaranteed or I am just getting lucky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes; it will happen after the call to the error handler; from the listener container's perspective, the entire spring-cloud-stream infrastructure is the record "listener".

Comment: What about the second question? If handle error itself fails will the commit still happen?

Comment: The behavior in that case depends on which version you are using; it is controlled by the listener container's error handler; with recent versions, the default error handler is a `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler` which will replay the record up to 10 times. With older versions, the default error handler was the `LoggingErrorHandler` which simply logged the error. In both cases (when retries are exhausted or immediately, respectively), the container will commit the offset - based on the error handlers `ackAfterHandle` property, which is true by default.